# Getting error while trying to deploy AWS lambda function through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws

I am getting the error while trying to deploy the AWS lambda.py through terraform script. I am very new to AWS Terraform and currently not able to figure out the error.

Please find the terroform script for lambda below:

```
resource "null_resource" "push_invoke_container" {
     depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.<xx>_ecr]
     triggers = {
      dockerfile = "${sha256(file("./lambda/Dockerfile"))}"
      app_code   = "${sha256(file("./lambda/main.py"))}"
    }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sh ./lambda/deploy.sh ${aws_ecr_repository.<xx>_ecr.name} ${aws_ecr_repository.<xx>_ecr.repository_url}"
    }
  }
 
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "invoker" {
    package_type  = "Image"
    depends_on    = [aws_ecr_repository.lambda_ecr, null_resource.push_invoke_container]
    function_name = "${var.app_prefix}_invoker_lambda_${var.environment}_test"
    image_uri     = "${aws_ecr_repository.lambda_ecr.repository_url}:latest" #"${aws_ecr_repository.lambda_ecr.repository_url}:latest"
    role          = var.invoker_lambda_role_arn_crawler
    timeout       = 90
    tracing_config {
      mode = "Active"
    }
    environment {
 

      variables = {
        CLUSTER          = "${aws_ecs_cluster.<xx>.id}",
        LAUNCH_TYPE      = "FARGATE",
        ASSIGN_PUBLIC_IP = "DISABLED",
        SUBNETS          = "${var.subnet_id}",
        SECURITY_GROUPS  = "${aws_security_group.<xx>_ecs_security_group.id}",
        TASK_DEFINITION  = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.<xx>.arn}"
      }
    }
  }
```

While running the above script through `terraform init`, I am getting the below error:

```
 Error: error configuring S3 Backend: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: RequestError: send request failed
│ caused by: Post "https://sts.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 52.xx.yyy.zzz:443: i/o timeout
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the Lambda code. To me it looks like you are not able to connect to the AWS APIs. Are you in a network that uses a proxy or something like that? Or some over zealous firewall?

Comment: We are not using any proxy. Also can you explain me zealous firewall. I dont think we are using any kind of firewall. Is there anything wrong in the above script. My lambda code is working fine.

Comment: Just look at the error. To me it does not look like it has anything to do with your code. But that is easy to verify. If you remove that code, does it work again? But looking at the error, you are not able to talk a AWS STS. You get a timeout. This usually happens, because you have a network problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are not logged into the AWS Account, if you are running it on your local try passing the security and access key for the aws account like below.

```
terraform init -backend-config="access_key=<your access key>" -backend-config="secret_key=<your secret key>"
```

Additionally, verify if the "region" is provided for the S3 backend.